# how would you find the solutions for $x$ where the quadratic $-27x^2+234x+169$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, quadratics

how would you find the solutions for $x$ where the quadratic $-27x^2+234x+169$ is a perfect square of an integer and $x$ is positive integer

I know that $x$ is from $1$ to $11$ because anything greater than $11$ makes the polynomial negative ,but how would compute the correct $x$ values without testing each of the 11 values?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Note that the $-27x^2$ dominates even for modest $x$, so there really aren't a whole lot of values to check.

Comment: x=0 is a solution

Comment: When I input values of the quadratic into Microsoft Excel, I actually get positive values only for the single digit numbers (less than 10). The solutions for x are 2 (which gives $529=23^2$) and 7 (which gives $484=22^2$).

Comment: Are you only looking for solutions in which x is an integer?

Comment: @Joe yes, x is a positive integer

Comment: $y^2=-27x^2+234x+169 \implies y^2+3(3x-13)^2=676 \implies (x,y)=(0,\pm13),(2,\pm23),(7,\pm22)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments point out, it's not really any faster to use algebraic number theory to solve the problem.

On the other hand, you can consider

$$y^2=-27x^2 + 18px + p^2$$

where $p$ is a prime number (your question is the special case $p=13$). Then solving this equation can be reduced to finding $a$, $b$ such that

$$a^2+ab+b^2=p^2\text{.}$$

Finding solutions to this last equation depends on whether the remainder of $p$ when divided by $3$ is $0$, $1$, or $2$.

Comment: you can also use the fact that $-2x^2+234x+169$ has to be a sum of two squares.

Answer (score 0):

$$ y = -27x^2 + 234x + 169 $$

This is a parabola with a vertex (in this case, the highest point)  at $x = -\frac{b}{2a}=-\frac{234}{2(-27)}=4\frac{1}{3}$ and $y=676$.

The roots are at $\dfrac{13}{9}(3 \pm 2\sqrt 3) \approx \{-0.67, 9.34\}$

So we only need to test $x = 0,1,2,\dots,9$

\begin{array}{r,|,c}
   x & y=-27 x^2 + 234 x + 169 \\
\hline
   0 & \color{red}{169=13^2} \\
   1 & 376 \\
   2 & \color{red}{529 = 23^2} \\
   3 & 628 \\
   4 & 673 \\
   5 & 664 \\
   6 & 601 \\
   7 & \color{red}{484 = 22^2}\\
   8 & 313 \\
   9 & 88 \\
\hline
\end{array}